# The coldest (the most endothermic) reaction

Tags: physical-chemistry, everyday-chemistry

What chemicals can you mix that causes *the coldest* (the most endothermic) reaction on a $\pu{kJ /kg}$ basis?

Comment: Do you mean a *chemical* reaction, or can it be *any* reaction? ie Are *nuclear* reactions acceptable? If not, please clarify by editing the title to include the word *chemical*.

Comment: Hm, I thought by "mix" you were only referring to a spontaneous reaction. It'd be nice if you could clarify if that's what you want. That could be a nice question on its own.

Answer (score 11):

There is an endothermic nuclear fusion for [the elements heavier than iron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusion_power#Mechanism). On Earth it's most likely a nuclear fission of light elements, like the one occurring in [early "dry" thermonuclear bombs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castle_Bravo), or a fission processes preceding D-T fusion reaction:

$$\ce{^7_3Li + ^1_0n -> ^3_1H + ^4_2He + ^1_0n - \pu{2.467 MeV}}$$

It's probably not the answer you'd expect, but the absolute values of thermal effects of any chemical reaction would be much lower in comparison.

Special thanks to [David Richerby](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/7412/david-richerby) for correcting me!

Comment: +1 Well, I suppose the OP was hoping for something of that magnitude, albeit, he was looking for *chemical* reaction that does it (non-existent). The OP ought to add some more details IMHO

Comment: @paracetamol I suspect that too, but the it's been asked about just a *reaction*, so I assumed it would be safe to mention nuclear fusion as #1 option.